# Calculate 30 hrs (24hrs+) time as single day in excel

Tags: excel

I have a restaurant log in following format.

```
Date | Time | Bill Number | Item | Price | Total Orders
```

The store time is 11 Am to next day 5 am. 
which will be over 24 hours.
But I want to calculate 11 am to next day 6 am as a single day.
Currently I am using Filter and sort to do it, but since data is of 2-3 months, is there a formula to sort it out? 
For example 
Jan 1st 11 am to Jan 2nd 6 am -> I want to calculate these time period as one day.

Comment: By "30-hours format", do you mean 30-hour-long days, or days running from 6:00 to 29:59?

Comment: Thank oyu for reply. yes 30 hours long day. 11 am to next day 5 am

Comment: Like the Stores Open at 11 am ( Sunday ) and closes on Monday 5 AM . I want to display only those data within it and so on. Currently I can use filter column and tick/untick the required one. But the problem is data is of whole about 2-3 months.

Comment: There's only 18 hours between 11am and 5am the following day, though.

Comment: @aaaaaa123456789 I have edited Question, Can you look once. I was wrong before.

Comment: Jan 1st 11am to Jan 2nd 6am is 19 hours so how do you get 30?

Comment: @SolarMike I am sorry for I meant 24 hrs format. Its confusing since they state 24 hrs format as 30 hours format. 
I didnt mean total 30 hours. So as Jan 1st passes, its one day, and Jan 2nd is another day. What I want is to combine these date and time ( Jan 1st 11 am to Jan 2nd 5 am) and make it as 1 day.

Comment: You state 11am to 5 am is over 24 hours - not true . It goes from 1 day into the next but only 18 hours... I am not confused...

Answer (score 0):

Solved it 
using this

> =TRUNC(B2+C2-TIME(6,0,0))